# Identify test classes dynamically

Tags: java, reflection, junit, testng

I required a solution to identify test classes from a jar file and execute them .That is my web application accept a jar file as input and identify test classes inside the jar and execute them and show the result.

Currently I am facing class not found exception whenever I am trying to access the class file from the jar.I think I need to add the external jar file to my class path?

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: You need to show at least some effort (e.g. actual code), in order for people to help you. Mind, that you will probably get some downvotes for this question, as people think you want to use SO as a 'solve that for me'-service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are some steps you can follow :

1. Get Jar file path
2. Read classes from it
3. Iterate through those classes
4. Get methods of each class
5. Check for annotations used in each class.
6. Latest versions of JUnit test classes have @Test annotation. So if you get `@org.junit.Test` annotation, you can say it is a test class.

   ```
       Method[] methods = classObject.getClass().getMethods();

       for (Method method : methods) {
           Annotation[] annotations = method.getAnnotations();
           for (Annotation annotation : annotations) {
               System.out.println(annotation.toString());
           }
       }
   ```

Output of this code -

```
@org.junit.Test(expected=class org.junit.Test$None, timeout=0)
@org.junit.After()
```

7. Once you find test class execute it.